# bonferroni adjustment with multiple groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bonferroni

I have 3 categorical metrics on cars

- Quality (values are high, medium , low) , Reliability (values are high,medium, low), Avg Life (long, medium, short)

and I have 4 groups A,B, C,D and they give ratings to the cars.

I want to know if there are pairwise differences between the groups in each category so I was going to perform pairwise t tests on the pairwise differences in means.

For example for the Quality category with the value of HIGH there are 6 pairwise differences. For the value of MEDIUM there are also 6 pairwise differences. 
AND for the value of LOW there are also 6 pairwise differences.

So for Quality category there are 18 t-test performed.  Similary for the Reliability and Avg life there are also 18 t-tests performed.

**In total there are 54 pairwise t-tests performed.**

I was going to use the  "hochberg" FDS p-value correction on the 6 pairwise t-tests in each value of the category.

For example, for the HIGH quality there are 6 pairwise differences and I was going to adjust those 6 pvalues using the  "hochberg" FDS.

**My question is - is that correct or should I be adjusting all 18 pvalues in the Quality category or should I be adjusting all 54 pvalue across all categories?**

thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to 'correct' at all? Procedures that deal with the increased rate of false positive errors in situations where there are multiple tests do so at the cost of power to avoid false negative errors. The are common situations in which 'correction' is unnecessary and therefore undesirable.

Comment: From what I've read you want to correct and the FDS is the least conservative.

Comment: What have you read that supports your statement "you want to correct"? The need for a 'correction' depends on the intended purpose and context of the analysis. Those are not present in the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: The advice is good, as far as it goes. However, you need to consider whether the cost of possible extra false positives makes the cost of missed true positives worthwhile. Those costs depend on what you are going to infer, decide, do, or believe in response to the data. Those things are unrelated to the nature of the null hypothesis.

Comment: I am trying to infer if there are pairwise differences as stated. So would you say to correct or not here?